# Do gas planets have surfaces suitable for landing on it?

Tags: landing, gas-giant

We already know, we are even taught at school that planets of the Solar System beyond Mars (Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune) are "gas-giants". But what does it mean exactly? Also, can any kind of ground vehicles land on its surface?

Comment: This question seems overly broad.  It has potential to be improved, so if it gets put on hold (likely) try improve it a bit.

Comment: This is already a result of another improvement. =)

Comment: "What is a gas giant?" is a basic question of Astronomy (which would make it Off-Topic for *this* SE, but not Astronomy.SE) , with an answer easily found on-line (Wikipedia, or any Astro-101 page) (which may or may not make it Off-T for SE, I'm not sure). // As you consider in your own answer, you may want to refine what you mean by "rovers" and "land" (a glider or airship could certainly travel on/through the upper atmosphere).

Comment: @hunter2 This question assumes that the definition of "gas giant" is clear, and we can easily decide about a planet that is it either a gas giant or not.

Comment: This question assumes that the definition of "gas giant" is clear, and we can easily decide about a planet that is it either a gas giant or not. Further discussion about the definition would be out of place below this question, I think.

Comment: Sure, it's pretty clear whether something is or is not a gas giant (for now, at least) - but you did ask "what does it mean exactly".  But OK, maybe I'm too focussed on language/semantics ... How about what you mean by 'land a rover'?  Does it count to have a blimp float in the atmosphere (at sub-orbital speed)?

Comment: I think, the definition of "landing" is quite obvious: reaching a surface and keeping on it. Fix me if I'm wrong - but actually I have no idea, how to explain this word more.

Also, we don't have to talk about rovers, any kind of ground vehicles might be good in this context. The matter is that neither wheels nor "legs" can't stand on gas that covers thousands of kilometres above the _actually solid_ core.

Comment: It is not obvious, in the context of a gas giant - see the example in my last comment. I guess your definition means 'wheels/legs on a solid surface'; what do you say of something that descends from orbit and never reaches a *solid* surface? // You need to use 'the at' for me to see your messages (like @ZoltánSchmidt). (I don't, because this is your question.)

Comment: @hunter2 (BTW I use 'at' usually, I don't how why I forgot it now) Actually, original question was that "Are gas giants have solid surface?" but that was also too broad. I have no idea for making it less broad anymore.

Comment: OK. Then I stick by my first comment (that the question should be on Physics or Astro SE), but think that Quonux has a good Answer (which you could Accept).   You could edit the lander question out again, and ask it seperately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question,

to answer the question, gas planets do probably have a solid core, because the pressure is so enormous that the atoms connect into a crystal-like structure.

We know that water for example can have more than 3 material states [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_X#Phases).

It is even possible/hypothesized that you get an metal if you compress a gas highly enough. This can explain the extreme magnetic fields of Jupiter [metallic hydrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen).

But you can't land on this solid core because the preasure is so enourmous.

Comment: Actually, my original question wasn't properly useful, so I rewrote it. The main question is about the ability to land on these planets. Fortunately, your answer is also related to it, so +1.

Comment: AFAIK, a solid metallic core is not yet accepted.   Hypothesized and studied - absolutely.   Maybe even *likely*, but not yet agreed-upon-as-fact.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't have. Cores of these gas giants are actually solid, but above them, there's a thick layer of gas, with thousands of kilometres of thickness. Obviously, its concentration is increasing as you approach the core, but it's not solid. Bodies are sinking into it, like into wateror quicksand. Except if they have something with smaller density than the gas (like hydroplan's "foots" with full of air)

Because of it, ground vehicles (like rovers) can't be placed on these planets. However, some kind of gliders would be effective in the atmosphere of these planets.

*(This is my first attempt to answer my own question, so I may be wrong. Please fix it if I am.)*

Comment: If the core is solid, then they arguably do have a solid surface at some point under the gas

Comment: The surface of the core, below thousand kilometres of superdense gas can hardly be called an actual surface, I think.

Comment: Why not? Earth has gasses covering its surface, not as much but its still there. You asked if they are 'only' gases, if they contain solids then no they aren't 'only' gasses. Is there some depth limit before we accept that the solids matter? if so at what point does this change from being ok to not being ok?

Comment: I think, in spacecraft defition, the surface is **solid** if bodies can stand on it without sinking down. For example, with this definition, I doubt that quicksand is solid, and actually (at least with some logic and sense), it must act like superdense gas: things are sinking in it while standing.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt Could you reference a body of work to back up this assertion?  Personal interpretations that don't have any supporting evidence -- especially regarding topics of this nature -- don't really make good accepted answers on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I know what I did wrong. It's because of my language mistakes, since I don't use words of physics in English often. Of course the definition of **solid** is obvious and irrefutable, so now I can see that I used the word wrong. I just wanted to explain that for example, you can't stand on quicksand without sinking down because of the gravitational force. Same on water and hyperdense gas - except if you use something that prevents you from sinking. (like hydroplans) Anyway, I didn't want to reinvent the wheel, so I will modify the question and the answer now

Comment: @RhysW I rewrote both the question and the answer. Would you like to keep this discussion in the comments?